# how to open a file in javascript with multiple extensions?

Tags: javascript

I am facing a small issue here...
I want to write a javascript function to open files with different extensions, I have already written a function that can open files but with their extensions hard written in the code, how to make this dynamic? Like Instead of opening "file1.pdf" or "file1.png" I want to store the extension as a variable and open it dynamically.
Here is the code:-

```
<script>
    function viewCM() {

        var transferID = document.getElementById("theTransferID").value;

        $.get("/Uploads/" + transferID + ".pdf")
            .done(function () {
            // Do something now you know the file exists.
                window.open("/Uploads/" + transferID + ".pdf", '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes');
            }).fail(function () {
            // File doesn't exist - do something else.
                alert("File was not found");
            })

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

The above function works perfectly with any type of extension but I can't manage to know how to make the extension dynamic
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: I don't get the file name from the server, The idea is simply that I have an upload button that uploads a file related to a specific "transfer" and I make the name of the uploaded file as `transferID.whatever extension` then when I want to open the file, I just write the code I posted. so I don't search the server for the file name.

Comment: I presume that `transferID` is being populated by some server-side code. If that's the case, get the server to return the file extension as well?

Comment: The `transferID` is populated by another javascript function when a row is selected and it is saved in a hidden field of a form. It has no relation with the file existing on the server, it is just the "filename" gotten from javascript code not by searching the server files

Comment: If you can determine the file extension on the front-end (perhaps another column in the row you mentioned?), you could do something similar (e.g. `var fileExtension = document.getElementById("???").value` and replace the `.pdf` in your code with `fileExtension`). Or you might pass the extension as an argument to `viewCM()` (i.e. the function signature becomes `viewCM(fileExtension)`.

Comment: @AlvinTeh I have already tried passing the extension as an argument to `viewCM()` but I failed to do "if statements" inside the code, I have 4 types of extensions ".pdf", ".png", ".docx", and ".xlsx"! Yet, I couldn't manage to check for the extension type inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue, I have made a some kind of "naive" workaround to solve this by making multiple `JavaScript` functions to open various types of files. 
It is as simple as : try to read a pdf file, if you can't then call a function that reads a png file etc!!

```
<script>
    function viewCM() {

        var transferID = document.getElementById("theTransferID").value;

        $.get("/Uploads/" + transferID + ".pdf")
            .done(function () {
            // Do something now you know the file exists.
                window.open("/Uploads/" + transferID + ".pdf", '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes');
            }).fail(function () {
            // File doesn't exist - call the next function.
                viewCMPng();
            })

        return true;
    }

    function viewCMPng() {

        var transferID = document.getElementById("theTransferID").value;

        $.get("/Uploads/" + transferID + ".png")
            .done(function () {
            // Do something now you know the file exists.
                window.open("/Uploads/" + transferID + ".png", '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes');
            }).fail(function () {
            // File doesn't exist - show alert message.
                alert("File was not found");
            })

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could find whats after the dot in the name to search for the type, just an idea.

```
 var afterDot = str.substr(str.indexOf('.'));
```

Then depending on type do your code.
(This can be very much improved).

EDITED:

```
 var transferID = document.getElementById("theTransferID").value; 
 var extension = transferID.substr(transferID.indexOf('.'));
```

Now you have this possibility:

```
if(extension == ".pdf"){  $.get("/Uploads/" + transferID + ".pdf")
        .done(function () {//...}
```

Comment: I don't get the file name from the server, The idea is simply that I have an upload button that uploads a file related to a specific "transfer" and I make the name of the uploaded file as `transferID.whatever extension` then when I want to open the file, I just write the code I posted. so I don't search the server for the file name.

Comment: I understood that, this code is javascript, not server side.
If you pass the filetype extension with the transferID.whateverExtension to a new variable and depending on it you chose one or other method.

Comment: I have tried that but I don't know how to use "if statements" to check for extension types inside the `viewCM()` function. How can I do that?

Comment: There are some bugs in this, if the name has a dot middle name this will fail, but as an idea for you to start I hope this helps.
You could check that "extension".lenght is always 3 or 4, or count number of dots in word to do the substr same number of dots.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on comments in the original question:

```
function viewCM(fileExtension) {
    var transferID = document.getElementById("theTransferID").value;

    $.get("/Uploads/" + transferID + "." + fileExtension)
        .done(function () {
        // Do something now you know the file exists.
            window.open("/Uploads/" + transferID + "." + fileExtension, '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes');
        }).fail(function () {
        // File doesn't exist - do something else.
            alert("File was not found");
        })

    return true;
}
```

You should not need to have any `if` statements within `viewCM()` if you can pass the file extension to the function (unless you're planning on performing some type of validation).

Comment: I don't get the extension dear,
I have (".pdf", ".png", ".docx", and ".xlsx")
how can i make cases based on these types

Comment: If you can't determine the file extension, unfortunately you won't be able to open the correct file on the front-end,.

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically adjust according to file type.
 means if pdf then open pdf viewer, excel should open excel
 window.open( file Name );

Comment: Can you please Clarify?

Comment: var link = $(linkData).attr("data-link"); // it can contains the full abosolute path of the file.
//then Write
window.open(link);

if browser supported file is there than it will open in browsers new tab like pdf , images etc...
and if it is excel , doc type files it will download directly